# "To save for something" vs "to save up for something"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Both sentences have the same number of hits on Google:

[save for my studies](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22save%20for%20my%20studies%22&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbvurP_ZneAhUMErwKHRd5A3wQ_AUICSgA&biw=1855&bih=960&dpr=1)

[save up for my studies](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=960&ei=ZbnNW_ryH4v-8gWymKywBg&q=%22save%20up%20for%20my%20studies%22&oq=%22save%20up%20for%20my%20studies%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39k1.72735.72829.0.72944.3.2.0.0.0.0.54.99.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.2.99...33i10k1.0.veSp6lwqURc)

So I'm curious, then what's the difference? Or there's no difference at all?

Example sentence:

> She won a scholarship, so the didn't have to save up for her studies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**up** there expresses the idea **accumulate**. Since **save** already has that meaning, the particle is just a kind of reinforcement of the idea.

> After months spent in space travel in Zero-G, astronauts will need to build up muscle.
>
> He is working odd jobs on Saturdays and saving up for a new bike.